# Characterization of the center of the fundamental group

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

As shown in this post:

[Center of fundamental group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3206274/center-of-fundamental-group)

We know that for any homotopy from the Identity to itself $F: X\times I \rightarrow X$

For any $x_0 \in X$,

the class of the loop $F(x_0, \cdot ):I\rightarrow X$ is in the center of the fundamental group $\pi_1(X, x_0)$

Is it possible to describe every element of the center in a similar way? (I'm guessinng not but can't come up with a counter-example)

If not, is there any known "nice" (and non trivial) property that caracterize those elements?